# Conditional install/uninstall of Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-2008, service, installation, conditional-statements, uninstallation

Using VS2008 TFS I have created a setup application that installs two Window Services.  The first service is always installed and uninstalled (and works fine--I'm using the installer class).  The second service is optional.  Depending a custom condition I set up determines whether the 2nd service is installed.  If requested the install works fine (using the installer class also).  However, I cannot get the service to uninstalled during the uninstall process.  The service exe is deleted, but the uninstall fails to uninstall the service.  I have set the Condition property on my assembly file (in the File System) and on all the custom actions associated with this assembly.  I suspect it is the custom action on the uninstall that is incorrect.  I am unable to remove the condition on the uninstall custom action--I get an error if I do (Unable to build custom action name  because it uses a conditionally installed file.)  I have tried other conditions but they too fail to uninstall the service.

To ensure my installer class is working okay, as a test, I removed all conditions and forced the 2nd service to install.  The install and uninstalled worked fine in this case.  Hope someone can help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can add an additional check in your condition, so that it only evaluates to true if the product is installed.  There is an [Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369297(VS.85).aspx) property that might give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Tried INSTALLED, but this did work for me.  Forcing the condition to true appears to have done the trick.  Not being sure what value to get it I tried the numeric value of 1.  This worked.  Install and Uninstall processes are working as planned whether the 2nd service was installed or not.  Thank you.

Comment: previous comment should have said... "Tried INSTALLED, but this did  NOT work for me."